# Javascript - construct an array with elements repeating from a string

Tags: javascript

Suppose there is a string `aba` and a limit 5. How can i create an array with elements repeating from the string till the limit is reached ?

e.g. `string = "aba"` and `limit = 5` will give new `array ["a","b","a","a","b"]`

As of now, my array fills with all characters then blank strings are repeated for the left indexes.

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let char = s.charAt(i);
    arr.push(char);
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

repeatedString("aba", 5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is almost there. You just need to let your index you use in `.charAt()` wrap back to 0 when you reach the length of the string. This can be done using the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) (`%`) with the length of the string like so:

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let char = s.charAt(i % s.length);
    arr.push(char);
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

repeatedString("aba", 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get an array of a padded string.

```js
var string = 'aba',
    limit = 5,
    result = Array.from(''.padStart(limit, string));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions for this:

- Calculate the times given string needs to be repeated.
- Repeat the string and extract `n` length string from it
- Split this string by individual characters

```js
function repeatedString(s, n) {
  const repeatCount = Math.ceil(n/s.length);
  return s.repeat(repeatCount).slice(0, n).split('');
}

console.log(repeatedString("aba", 5))
```